# Google search showing wrong title for my webpage when searching

Tags: seo, google-search, html-title

My website `<title>` tag value is as below

```
<title>Neuron</title>
```

and the website url is `www.neuron.ae`

but when searching it through google the title is coming as

[image: Neuron]

the url is coming as correct `www.neuron.ae` title is showing wrong.
How can I show the correct title as in my `<title>` tag?

**Search Query I am using**

```
Neuron
```

**head tag info**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/29d44f68/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/29d44f68/css/bootstrap-yii.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/148ab19f/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/29d44f68/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Neuron</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Third party administrators, Neuron, TPA service provider, Insurance, Health, Reinsurance services, Neuron for brokers, Neuron, Wellbeing, Insurance Brokers,
in UAE, in Dubai, In DSO, Dubai Silicon Oasis, Neuron managed care, Your heath is in safe hands, Online Claims, wellbeing, medical insurance" />
<meta name="description" content="Neuron is one of the leading Third Party Administrators (TPAs) in the UAE and MENA region. Showing steady growth since inception, Neuron currently employs around 150 professionals ranging from experienced medical staff to business development and network specialists. Neuron provides outsourced administration and management services to clients in the Middle East for all areas of insurance administrations." />
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: What are the search queries you're using?

Comment: @socialpiranha search query is 'My Insurance'

Comment: @socialpiranha the website details are just example of mine..problem is with other data

Comment: @socialpiranha edited my question with actual data. please check. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks, can you post the entire `head` of your website? (You can anonymize the data, I just want to see if you have any meta tags that are messing things up)

Comment: @socialpiranha added head of website except the javacript function in it

Comment: I don't know if this is important, but one thing I notice is that your page doesn't have any `lang` attributes. Since the page is in English, it wouldn't hurt to add `lang="en"` to the html start tag.

Comment: @MrLister its bilingual website

Comment: @Sachu Oh... I didn't see any "choose language" boxes on the page, sorry. Is the display langauge chosen on the server side? In that case, you can also add the attribute dynamically.

Comment: @MrLister www.neuron.ae/ar will lead to arabic website

Answer (score 3):

You can't control the page title and meta description 100%, at the end Google will choose the best title and meta description for the users.

Many factors affect the page title and meta description like search query, website name and backlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Well Google Search Engine typically display 50-60 character of title tag, whereas your title character is less then 55 characters, so include some more character to your title tag around 55 character and hopefully it will work.